# Angular 2 Typescript - Promise Anonymous function

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular-promise, es6-promise

I'm working on a login API and encountered this problem that I've marked wit a comment:

```
this.service.login(this.user).then(res => this.api.controlData(res))
.then(e => function(e){
    console.log(e); // NOTHING HAPPENS HERE

    if(!e){
       console.log(this.getMsg());
    }else{
       this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
    }
}).catch (function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

So nothing happens in my anonymous function.
**However**, this does work:

```
this.service.login(this.user).then(res => this.api.controlData(res))
.then(e => this.functionAnonymeMaisenFaiteNon(e))
.catch (function (error) {
    console.log(error);
 });

 private functionAnonymeMaisenFaiteNon(e: boolean){
    if(!e){
       console.log(this.getMsg());
    }else{
       this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
    }
 }
```

I'm not quite sure what the anonymous function does different.

Comment: Ok i find this solution, i should only use (e => {) wich is is a typescript anonym function ...

Comment: Yes, using lambdas binds the right `this` context.